# paper-icon-item receiving tab focus?

Tags: polymer-1.0, paper-elements

This seems to be a newly introduced issue on Polymer 1.0+, wherein the paper-icon-item element is receiving focus when tabbing through the page.  In the past, if the paper-icon-item contained a paper-input, the paper-input would would receive the focus, not the paper-icon-item container.  Has anyone else noticed this issue, and perhaps have a resolution?